# iOS Development: Adding Greystripe ads to my app via AdWhirl is causing a crash

Tags: iphone, ios, adwhirl

One of my free apps is making enough ad requests to cause really low fill rates, so I decided to add another ad network alongside iAd and Admob to my app.  With AdWhirl, this is a very easy process.  You drop the Greystripe SDK folder into XCode and enable the Greystripe adapter in the AdWhirl code.  That's it!  Unfortunately, it's crashing :)

The Greystripe ad banner loads fine, but as soon as it tries to dealloc, it crashes in the following code in the AdWhirlAdapterGreystrip.m file...

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [innerContainer release];   //<--Crash here
  [outerContainer release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

I don't know the AdWhirl SDK code at all and, before I dive into it, I was hoping someone else has seen this or can give me some ideas of where to look.

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current release version of our adapter has a bug in the new `stopBeingDelegate` method, which as Bastian says, results in a bad release.

To solve this just comment out:

```
[GSAdView adViewForSlotNamed:kGSBannerSlotName delegate:nil];
```

from the `stopBeingDelegate` method in `AdWhirlAdapterGreystripe.m`

This is also [reported in google code](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/issues/detail?id=153#c1). If you have a chance please "star" this issue, so AdWhirl will merge this fix into the release.

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Greystripe ;)</sub>

Comment: thanks, josh! and good work!  i'll star this issue right away.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a crash in this location means that innerContainer was already released earlier. Or was never retained properly.